# CS50 vigenere in Python, bug in encyphering if plaintext has non alphabetic characters

Tags: python, debugging, cs50, vigenere

I would like some help with the pset 6 Vigenere in python. My implementation in C was alright, but there is a bug in the Python code that confuses me. The program enciphers correctly up until it finds a non alphabetic character. After the non alphabetic character i should not increment, but what happens when running the program is that the key updates itself once more but never again in the nexts iterations of the loop with alphabetic characters. And what upsets me is that in C the same implementation worked perfectly. I guess there is something wrong with the conditions inside the loop, but I don't see what. This is what I get running the program in C and in Python, only the first enciphers correctly:

[image]

Here is the code, thanks in advance for your help.

```
from cs50 import get_string
import sys


def main():

    # Check usage and key
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 or not sys.argv[1].isalpha():
        print("Usage: python vigenere.py k")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Prompt user for plaintext
    plaintext = get_string("plaintext:  ")

    # Cipher text
    print("ciphertext: ", end="")

    # Set keyword iteration counter
    i = 0
    key = sys.argv[1]
    len_key = len(key)
    keyword = shift(key[i])

    for c in plaintext:

        # Take care of uppercase character
        if c.isupper():
            print(chr(((ord(c) - 65 + keyword) % 26) + 65), end="")

        # Take care of lowercase character
        elif c.islower():
            print(chr(((ord(c) - 97 + keyword) % 26) + 97), end="")

        # Take care of non alphabetic character
        else:
             print(c, end="")

        # Take care of keyword counter
        if i < len_key - 1 and plaintext[i].isalpha():
            i = i + 1
            keyword = shift(key[i])
        elif i == len_key - 1 and plaintext[i].isalpha():
            i = 0
            keyword = shift(key[i])

    print()


# Function shift value of each carachter of keyword
def shift(char):
    if char.isupper():
        value = ord(char) - 65
    else:
        value = ord(char) - 97
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Looks like this is simply from the condition `if i < len_key - 1 and plaintext[i].isalpha()` - if `plaintext[i]` is non-alphabetic then `i` will not be incremented. In the next iteration of the loop `i` is still the same so `plaintext[i]` is still the same non-alphabetic character, and `i` never increases. What do you expect it to do? Continue to the next alphabetic character? If so you could perhaps add a condition `elif not plaintext[i].isalpha(): i += 1`

Comment: Or perhaps you meant to use `c.isalpha()` instead of `plaintext[i].isalpha()` - that would make more sense

Comment: I did not explain it correctly, I will edit it. After the non alphabetic character i should not increment. What happens when running the program is that the key updates itself once more but never again in the nexts iterations of the loop with alphabetic characters. And what upsets me is that in C the same implementation worked perfectly. I guess there is something wrong with the conditions inside the loop, but I don't see what. Thanks!

Comment: If `i` does not increment then how can the key update itself?   The line `keyword = shift(key[i])` is only carried out if `plaintext[i].isalpha()` is True. And as `i` doesn't increment we are stuck on the non-alphabetic character.

Comment: That's right, i should increment only if plaintext[i].isalpha(). What is happening is that the i is incrementing with the first alphabetic character after a non alphabetic character, and then never again, when it should with the successive alphabetic characters. This is what I get running the program in C and in Python, the first works alright:  ./vigenere abcd
plaintext:  a1bcabcd
ciphertext: a1cedbdf    python vigenere.py abcd
plaintext:  a1bcabcd
ciphertext: a1cdbcde

Comment: Alright, I made a stupid mistake and did not test your second comment in the right way! I replaced plaintext[i].isalpha() with c[i].isalpha. And with c.isalpha() works OK. And of course, that makes much more sense. Thanks a lot Stuart!